# How many CloudTableClients should an Azure application use?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

When using a CloudTableClient I see three options:
(1) Create a new client each time access to the Cloud Table is required.
(2) Create a new client at the start of the application and share it across all resources that require access.
(3) Create a new client for each cloud table type at the start of the application.

Assume this is contained in a data access layer and the implementation is easily interchangeable.

Comment: If you're using different authentication for different tables you'll need more. Are you using shared key on a single account for all tables or something different? Are there other reasons you're considering creating more clients?

Answer (score 1):

One should suffice unless you want to specify different configuration options for each CloudTableClient (eg - different AuthN styles etc).